# iPhone 4S' home button isn't working properly

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4S' home button isn't working properly. It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Could it be because of the dust?

If dust is the problem how do I proceed with removing dust particles? And, if not, **what can I do?**

Comment: I recommend scheduling a Genius appointment at an Apple store.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the dust, but you could enable AssistiveTouch, which will place a round button on the screen, which gives you access to all the home button features, and more like volume, gestures, etc. To switch it on go to `Settigngs -> General -> Accessibility` Scroll down to AssistiveTouch and turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

you can search for specific tools, which can help you in removing dust particles. Drop into any of the Apple stores, and ask for support.

If that's not possible for you, then you can use methods described in this post i found while googling. [how to fix home button](http://iphonage.com/iphone-home-button-broken-how-to-fix/). Hope this information works for you.